# Each loop in bi-dimensional array in jade for meteor

Tags: meteor, pug

I'm using mquandalle/meteor-jade, but I can't seem to be able to loop in a bi dimensional array. 
The homeList function returns an [[objects],[objects],[objects]]
So I want to do

```
each homeList
  //do stuff
    each object
      //do other stuff
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of the inner loop is `this`:

```
each homeList
  //do stuff
    each this
      //do other stuff
```

In an [upcoming release](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/3560) there will be a way to assign names in such cases.